# load css via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-routing

I have this very simple .htaccess rule for my site

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

I routes perfectly but it is not good enough to load css and javascript files located in very different directory.

For e.g. My php files are located like this

```
 DOCUMENT ROOT/*.php
```

and My CSS files are located somewhere like this

```
DOCUMENT ROOT/templates/example/ui/css/xyz.css
```

I want the .htaccess rule such that if i write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/xyz.css"/>
```

it loads the css file from

```
 http://example.com/templates/example/ui/css/xyz.css
```

I dont know if its possible or not. If not then please suggest any alternative ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an additional rule for css loading:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/

RewriteRule ^(css/.+)$ /templates/example/ui/$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: the server responded with 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/example/css/layout.css

Comment: Why it is `localhost/example/css/layout.css` should it not be: `localhost/css/layout.css` as per your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/xyz.css"/>`?

Comment: had it been localhost/example/css/layout.css, then, what would it be?

Comment: .htaccess rules do change a bit depending on the path they are in. Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Most likely your `DocumentRoot` is  set to `/htdocs/` instead of `/htdocs/example/`

Comment: check updated code now, make sure it is in `/example/.htaccess` and your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/htdocs/`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your current rule is more or less a catch-all rule, you want to add the following rules below `RewriteEngine on`, but above the catch-all rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/templates/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ /templates/example/ui/$1.css [L]
```

This rule checks if the url doesn't already start with /templates. Then it rewrites all urls ending with .css to the given url. The condition is to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: the server responded with 
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/example/css/layout.css

Comment: This answer answers the question you asked above. If you use a different url on your server, you should have asked it like that in the first place. You can still use this answer, but you'll need to use `^example/(.*)` instead of `^(.*)`.